# Tailwind css - responsive padding order overring priority

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a logo header issue - where in mobile I want the padding to be 16px - but in desktop padding to be 128px.

```
<header className="p-sm md:px-xl">xxx</header>
```

but the desktop version is still showing the mobile padding?

I can see a file where the override looks correct called globals.css -- but then I see p-sm override in another location under `<styles>`

its the way that next/document is being used to integrate the head - something has created various inline styles that override the tailwinds css

---

update

so we have made a UI lib on its own repo with tailwindcss -- and recently replaced the UI components on another repo (also its tailwindcss defined) -- I think what's happened is when we swapped over to the UI lib components which is its own node module -- it replicated the tailwindcss twice -- there is an override happening that is knocking the styling off.

Comment: Can you share your code, please ? Like your navbar part or something

Comment: No its on a private repo/machine etc..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the wrong syntax when defining your screens.

You shouldn't use `md-` or `lg-` when creating a responsive design but `md:` and `lg:`.

Here's the documentation: [Link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design).

Your code should look like this:

```
<header className="p-sm md:px-xl">xxx</header>
```

If you don't have custom sizing, you can use this code instead:

```
<header className="p-[16px] md:px-[128px]">xxx</header>
```

Comment: Also notice you're using both `p` and `px`. So while your `md:px` works only on bigger screens, your `p` is active on all screen (it's like typing `p-[16px] md:px-[128px] md:py-[16px]`. In other words, you shouldn't mix them this way, it's unreadable. use either `px`, `p` or `py`. If you want to use both `px` and `p`, define each one of them for both screens.

Comment: no the code was as you have it : -- the problem is inline styles are being set and overriding it - but I cant see how its been setup